# Two tables with same ID in Laravel project

Tags: database, laravel

I have two tables that must have the same id. 
This is the first that I have alredy in DB.

```
Schema::create('devices', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('device_type', 20)->nullable();
        $table->date('purchase_date')->nullable();
        $table->date('activation_date')->nullable();
        $table->date('deactivation_date')->nullable();
        $table->bigInteger('companyId')->unsigned();
        $table->timestamps();

    });
```

Should the second table look like this?

```
Schema::create('device_news', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->float('x', 10);
        $table->float('y', 10);
        $table->time('time')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('deviceId');
        $table->timestamps();

        $table->foreign('deviceId')->references('id')->on('devices');
    });
```

I'm new to this, I'm a little confused about it

Comment: So what is your concern? Tell us..

Comment: I need one ID for both tables in DB. My mentor tells me this is not right., because in DB i have id and foreign id

Comment: Your mentor's suggestion is right. Your  `devices` table `id` relation with `device_news` table `deviceId`. So basically `deviceId` actually `id` of `devices` table.

Comment: But how can I make same id in two diferent tables?

Comment: No no, Both tables with the same id create an issue in the past.

Comment: Can I than make second table only with deviceId that reference on id from first table?

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use [laravel ORM relationship](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one), you don't need to have the same Id but you can use device id as a foreign key in device_news:

In the device model you can add code like this :

```
public function deviceNew()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\DeviceNew');
}
```

And in the device new model you can add code like this :

```
public function device()
{
    return $this->belongTo('App\Device', 'deviceId');
}
```

Then you can call the device_news table from the device model like this :

```
$new = Device::find(1)->deviceNew;
```

**EDIT** : 
Try this too to meet your mentor expectation

In your DeviceNew model add this property :

```
public $incrementing = false;
```

Then every time you store the device make sure you make the device new too, like this :

```
$device = new Device();
$device->device_type = "type";
// Add other field too
$device->save();

$deviceNew = new DeviceNew();
$deviceNew->id = $device->id;
// Add other field too
$deviceNew->save();
```

Comment: Is it even possible make same id for both tables? In DeviceNew Model i have protected $fillable = [ 'id', 'x', 'y', 'time', 'deviceId']; but I need only one id here.

Comment: Can I know what the reason you need to use a same id for both tables?

Comment: Are you want to match the table by the id itself without foreign key?

Comment: The mentor told me this is how it should be. I make with relation hasOne, but he require that tables DeviceNew and Device have same id.

Comment: Did he mean the same primary id? not foreign relations?

Comment: Yes, I need that

Comment: Then you need to store the device_news id manually after you store something in the device table and get the id, wait I will make an edit in my answer to add that

Comment: I already have id's in Device, and I need that id's in DeviceNew. You understand?

Comment: yes, so you must insert it manually in devicenew without auto_increment right?

Comment: When I insert it manualy in Device (via CRUD), that id's must be shown in DeviceNew

Comment: Im inserting manualy id Device table. Now in new table called DeviceNew i need to show all that devices that I have inserted

Comment: If you already did that, then you can try :
$device = Device::find(1); //this is sample the device that you have
DeviceNew::find($device->id)

Comment: But first I need to make table with same id like in first table.